# TCP and UDP connection

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

just wondering if should it be allowed to bind socket to the same ip/port on the client side and server side like in the snippet below?

```
    static TcpListener TcpListener;
    static UdpClient ServerSideUdpClient;
    static TcpClient ServerSideTcpClient;

    static TcpClient ClientSideTcpClient;
    static UdpClient ClientSideUdpClient;
    static NetworkStream TcpStream;

    static byte[] Buffer = new byte[4096];
    static byte[] Data1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    static byte[] Data2 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10 };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3666);
        TcpListener.Start();
        TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TCPConnectCallback, null);

        ClientSideTcpClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        ClientSideTcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 3666);
        ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, TcpReceiveCallback2, null);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        ClientSideUdpClient = new UdpClient();
        ClientSideUdpClient.Client.Bind(ClientSideTcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint);
        ClientSideUdpClient.BeginReceive(UdpReceiveCallback2, null);
        ClientSideUdpClient.Send(Data1, Data1.Length, ClientSideTcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint);

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        ClientSideUdpClient.Send(Data1, Data1.Length);
        ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().Write(Data1, 0, Data1.Length);
        ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().Write(Data1, 0, Data1.Length);

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        ClientSideUdpClient.Send(Data1, Data1.Length);
        ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().Write(Data1, 0, Data1.Length);
        ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().Write(Data1, 0, Data1.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("ClientSideTcpClient " + "Local: " + ClientSideTcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + " --- Remote: " + ClientSideTcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ClientSideUdpClient " + "Local: " + ClientSideUdpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + " --- Remote: " + ClientSideUdpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void TCPConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ServerSideTcpClient = TcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
        TcpStream = ServerSideTcpClient.GetStream();

        ServerSideUdpClient = new UdpClient(ServerSideTcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint);
        ServerSideUdpClient.BeginReceive(UdpReceiveCallback, null);

        TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TCPConnectCallback, null);
        TcpStream.BeginRead(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, TcpReceiveCallback, null);

        ServerSideTcpClient.GetStream().Write(Data2, 0, Data2.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("ServerSideTcpClient " + "Local: " + ServerSideTcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + " --- Remote: " + ServerSideTcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    }

    private static void TcpReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ServerSideTcpClient.Connected) return;

            int receivedBytesLength = TcpStream.EndRead(result);

            if (receivedBytesLength <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[receivedBytesLength];

            Array.Copy(Buffer, 0, receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytesLength);
            TcpStream.BeginRead(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, TcpReceiveCallback, null);

            Console.WriteLine("Server side Tcp: " + BitConverter.ToString(receivedBytes));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server side Tcp exception: " + exception);
        }
    }

    private static void TcpReceiveCallback2(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ClientSideTcpClient.Connected) return;

            int receivedBytesLength = ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().EndRead(result);

            if (receivedBytesLength <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[receivedBytesLength];

            Array.Copy(Buffer, 0, receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytesLength);
            ClientSideTcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, TcpReceiveCallback2, null);

            Console.WriteLine("Client side Tcp: " + BitConverter.ToString(receivedBytes));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client side Tcp exception: " + exception);
        }
    }

    private static void UdpReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] packetContent = ServerSideUdpClient.EndReceive(result, ref client);

            ServerSideUdpClient.BeginReceive(UdpReceiveCallback, null);
            if (!ServerSideUdpClient.Client.Connected) ServerSideUdpClient.Connect(client);
            ServerSideUdpClient.Send(Data2, Data2.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Server side Udp: " + BitConverter.ToString(packetContent));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server side Udp exception: " + exception);
        }
    }

    private static void UdpReceiveCallback2(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] packetContent = ClientSideUdpClient.EndReceive(result, ref client);

            ClientSideUdpClient.BeginReceive(UdpReceiveCallback2, null);
            if (!ClientSideUdpClient.Client.Connected) ClientSideUdpClient.Connect(client);

            Console.WriteLine("Client side Udp: " + BitConverter.ToString(packetContent));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client side Udp exception: " + exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Local and Remote EndPoint are the same for both TCP and UDP client on the server and client side.

Is there any downfall for this?

Maybe it's working only locally?

Won't UDP and TCP packets arrive one after another (the same queue for UDP and TCP)?

Comment: *"...  bind socket to the same ip/port on the client side and server side ..."* - and any data should end up where? This is basically like a house with a single address (IP), two residents with the same name (port) and two letter boxes (sockets): if a letter arrives, which letter box should it be placed in? They cannot be distinguished.

Comment: TCP and UDP are completely separate protocols. TCP port 12345 _is not_ UDP port 12345. IP knows nothing about ports. Both TCP and UDP use ports (addresses) in the same number range, but they are different.

Comment: Note thought that I cannot see your code doing *"... bind socket to the same ip/port on the client side and server side ..."*. The TCP client does not bind at all it only connects (and implicitly binds to some random ephemeral port. The UDP client uses the same local port as the TCP client too. Having TCP and UDP bind to the same IP and port is perfectly fine, but this is not what I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's seems that i just lack knowledge on this specific topic. So (if i understand it correctly) TcpClient and UdpClient are creating separate sockets but they can bind to the same port locally and listen for incoming packets. Furthermore each socket have it's own queue for incoming packets and one of the network layers distinguish which protocol it is and address it to correct socket?